# DVWP Error Grouping

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, data-view-web-part

I have a data view web part which was migrated to a SharePoint 2010 environment. It had a query parameter to group by month(calculated column) and filter by year.

Since the migration it has been throwing an error, and had to recreate it but if page size exceeds 250 it throws an error.

Any ideas please on why this is happening

---

Yes the list has lookup columns, and i do have indexed columns

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because of the [list throttling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx). How many items are in your list? Do you have any indexed columns? Does the list have lookup columns?